# WCF, IDispatchOperationSelector : return custom FaultException when operation not exist

Tags: c#, wcf

In my WCF service, I am using a custom `DispatchOperationSelector` like that :

```
class DispatchByBodyElementOperationSelector : IDispatchOperationSelector
{
    Dictionary<XmlQualifiedName, string> dispatchDictionary;

    public DispatchByBodyElementOperationSelector(Dictionary<XmlQualifiedName, string> dispatchDictionary)
    {
        this.dispatchDictionary = dispatchDictionary;            
    }

    #region IDispatchOperationSelector Members

    private Message CreateMessageCopy(Message message, XmlDictionaryReader body)
    {
        Message copy = Message.CreateMessage(message.Version,message.Headers.Action,body);
        copy.Headers.CopyHeaderFrom(message,0);
        copy.Properties.CopyProperties(message.Properties);
        return copy;
    }

    public string SelectOperation(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message)
    {
        XmlDictionaryReader bodyReader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();

        XmlQualifiedName lookupQName = new XmlQualifiedName(bodyReader.LocalName, bodyReader.NamespaceURI);
        message = CreateMessageCopy(message,bodyReader);
        if (dispatchDictionary.ContainsKey(lookupQName))
        {
            return dispatchDictionary[lookupQName];
        }
        else
        {
            //Here : operation not found !
            //this doesn't work : throw new FaultException<ValidationException>(new ValidationException()); 

            return null;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I want to return a custom `FaultException` if the operation requested doesn't exist (instead of return `null` and having a `ArgumentNullException` exception like in my code).

How can I do that ?

**EDIT :**

result with "throw new FaultException(new ValidationException());" instruction :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://test.com/utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://test.com/secext-1.0.xsd">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2015-09-15T07:48:23.199Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2015-09-15T07:53:23.199Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="fr-FR">The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
               <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
               <Message>The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.</Message>
               <StackTrace>at Demo.Demo11WcfService.DispatchByBodyElementOperationSelector.SelectOperation(Message&amp; message) in d:\Activite\TRACA\DEV\Main\DemoSolution2\DemoSolution2\Demo.Demo11WcfService\DispatchByBodyOperationSelector.cs:line 47
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.CustomDemuxer.GetOperation(Message&amp; request)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)</StackTrace>
               <Type>System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Demo.DomainModel.Demo11.ValidationException]</Type>
            </ExceptionDetail>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Result expected :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://test.com/utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://test.com/secext-1.0.xsd">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2015-09-15T07:49:55.610Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2015-09-15T07:54:55.610Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="fr-FR">The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ValidationException xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Demo.DomainModel.Demo11" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <reasonField i:nil="true"/>
            </ValidationException>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment apparently, I'll leave this here (feel free to delete the answer if that's inappropriate):

Have you tried just throwing a custom `FaultException` instead of returning `null`?

Comment: It is not a good solution because if I do that, i obtain a classic fault exeption from the WCF dispacher. Not my custom fault exeption. See my EDIT in my original post.